# Space Complexity of an algorithm when no extra space is used

Tags: algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

Consider an algorithm that uses no extra variables except the given input.

How to represent the space complexity in BigO Notation?

Comment: How would you represent the Time Complexity of a program that took the same amount of time no matter how big the input?

Comment: @ScottHunter I think what is really being asked is do you count the input size into the space complexity? I think it's not trivial to a beginner that e.g. a sorting algorithm that performs in-place sorting in an input array in the millions of elements is considered of constant space complexity. But we have the answer: The input data is not counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O(1)`

Where it requires a constant amount of additional space namely 0.